# Firestore query with collectionGroup.whereEqualTo returns empty result

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore database is currently set up as such (not enough reputation to insert an image):

[image]

I added index in database and security roles:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, get, list: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /{path=**}/Users/{user} {
      allow read, write, get, list: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm making such a query and get 0 (query returns empty result) :

```
    db.collectionGroup("Users")
        .whereEqualTo("id", "q2v7gi104XYCyHWGPuIPTvxdgP63")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { docs ->
            Log.i(TAG, "${docs.size()}")
         }
```

If I do so:

```
db.collectionGroup("Users")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { docs ->
                Log.i(TAG, "${docs.size()}")
             }
```

it works, query return all users.

Why doesn't it work with "whereEqualTo"?

Comment: Show us how did you create the index.

Comment: ![](http://joxi.ru/bmoRqYPHObzGRr)

If there was no index, there would be an error, but there are no errors

Comment: Show us the details of the index, please.

Comment: !(http://joxi.ru/LmGgLy6iBkWodm)

Comment: At first glance the values look the same, but we should always validate such an assumption with code. I recommend looping over the docs in your final snippet (without the query) and checking: `Log.i("'"+TAG, doc.id+"', "+(doc.id == "q2v7gi104XYCyHWGPuIPTvxdgP63"))`.

Comment: Yes, of course I checked
doc.id = "q2v7gi104XYCyHWGPuIPTvxdgP63"

Comment: It can also be seen in the database image